# Permission Denial : permission.MAPS_RECEIVE due to sender com.google.android.apps.maps

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I imported a map sample and run the application, Upon running the application it showing a white map screen.

I found a warning in Locat saying

`W/BroadcastQueue(306): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.google.android.maps.api.action.TOKEN_RESPONSE flg=0x10 pkg=com.example.mapdemo (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{42554900 5306:com.example.mapdemo/u0a216} (pid=5306, uid=10216) requires com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE due to sender com.google.android.apps.maps (uid 10031)`

I checked the manifest thouroughly and unable to trace any issues. Please find my manifest permissions below.

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Please let me know the possible solutions

Update: I'm able to get rid of that warning.The mistake is I am using v1 api key.
But still I'm unable to get the map. Showing white screen without any warnings or errors.

Regards, 
Sha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your manifest has

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Also make sure that you have your key (debug or release) set in the maps api console.

Comment: Thanks . But I'm using all those things in my manifest.Even thought I'm getting permission denial warning.

Comment: The mistake is I am using v1 api key. But still I'm unable to get the map. When I reset the key in API keys. Everything is going perfect.

Comment: Is this still required? As far as i know the latest google play update takes care of this...?

Answer (score 1):

**This permission told by `@Gabe Sechan` is now completely unnecessary. The latest update of Google Play Services 3.1.59 made it useless. As a result, it can be removed.**

So be quiet sure to update the latest google play services.